# Dynamic Text Field - Android

Tags: android, xml, mobile

I'm trying to create a dynamic text field that will take multiple fields of user input during a single activity, do a calculation in the java file, and then display the resulting value within the SAME activity in a text field.

Is there any way of doing this? I just figured out that I can't edit strings.xml dynamically, so are there any structures I can use that will allow me to constantly change the values?

Thanks all.

Comment: What View are you using?

Comment: Sorry, this is my first android app...could you explain what that is real quick so I can figure it out for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will be pretty straight forward:

```
String yourTextValue = "text";
TextView myTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView1);
myTextView.setText(yourTextValue);
```

Just call setText() with your String value (whatever it may be) each time you want to change the value of your TextView.